How to merge multiple dendrogram with a heatmap in R?
I was trying to make a heatmap and hierarchical clustering with a dendrogram of samples.
I'm trying to follow this particular thread from StackOverflow(Merging multiple hclust objects (or dendrograms))
I have a large dataframe,
    head(joined_df_sorted)
# A tibble: 6 × 24
  chrom   start     end EE85756 EE85757 EE85770 EE85775 EE85784 EE87786 EE87787 EE87788 EE87789 EE87790 EE87811 EE87812 EE87813 EE87814 EE87815 EE87893 EE87894 EE87895 EE87896 EE87897
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 chr1  1000001 2000000       3       4       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3
2 chr1  3000001 4000000       3       4       3       3       3       8       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3
3 chr1  4000001 5000000       3       4       3       3       3      13       3       3       8       3       3       3       3       3       6       3       3       3       3       3
4 chr1  5000001 6000000       3       4       3       3       3      10       3       3       7       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3
5 chr1  6000001 7000000       3       4       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3
6 chr1  7000001 8000000       3       4       3       3       3       7       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3       3
# ℹ 1 more variable: chromid <chr>

What I have done till now is,
    #Joining first 2 columns for making unique row name
    joined_df_sorted$chromid <- paste0(joined_df_sorted$chrom, "_", joined_df_sorted$start)

#Keeping only required columns
joined_df_sorted2 <- as.data.frame(joined_df_sorted[,c(24,4:23)])


#making first column as row name
joined_df_sorted3<-joined_df_sorted2
joined_df_sorted3X <- joined_df_sorted3[,-1]
rownames(joined_df_sorted3X) <- joined_df_sorted3[,1]

## transposing the dataframe without changing datatype
install.packages("sjmisc")
library(sjmisc)

joined_df_sorted3X_t<-joined_df_sorted3X %>% 
  rotate_df(cn = FALSE)

CanCohortDat<-joined_df_sorted3X_t

BileDuct  <- c("EE87786",   "EE87787",  "EE87788",  "EE87789",  "EE87790")
Breast <-  c("EE87811", "EE87812",  "EE87813",  "EE87814",  "EE87815")
Gastric <- c("EE87893", "EE87894",  "EE87895",  "EE87896",  "EE87897")
Healthy <- c("EE85756", "EE85757",  "EE85770","EE85775",    "EE85784")

#Separate clustering of 4 distinct datasource
h1 <- hclust(dist(CanCohortDat[BileDuct,]))
h2 <- hclust(dist(CanCohortDat[Breast,]))
h3 <- hclust(dist(CanCohortDat[Gastric,]))
h4 <- hclust(dist(CanCohortDat[Healthy,]))

#merge 4 clusters
hc <- as.hclust(merge(merge(merge(
  as.dendrogram(h1), as.dendrogram(h2)), as.dendrogram(h3)), 
  as.dendrogram(h4)))

CanCoh <-CanCohortDat[c(BileDuct, Breast, Gastric, Healthy),]


cohort_annotation <- data.frame(Region = c(rep("BileDuct", length(BileDuct)), 
                                           rep("Breast", length(Breast)),
                                           rep("Gastric", length(Gastric)),
                                           rep("Healthy", length(Healthy))),
                                row.names = c(BileDuct, Breast, Gastric, Healthy))


#Heatmap
pheatmap(CanCoh , cluster_rows = hc, 
         annotation_row = cohort_annotation)


#############ERROR##############
`use_raster` is automatically set to TRUE for a matrix with more than 2000
columns You can control `use_raster` argument by explicitly setting TRUE/FALSE
to it.

Set `ht_opt$message = FALSE` to turn off this message.
'magick' package is suggested to install to give better rasterization.

Set `ht_opt$message = FALSE` to turn off this message.
Error in hclust(get_dist(t(submat), distance), method = method) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)
In addition: Warning message:
The input is a data frame, convert it to the matrix. 

My Output should look like this: EE* are the different samples that should be at y axis and grouped by the merged dendrogram and x-axis should display the chromosome location.


What you used looks like the package ComplexHeatmap (from the error message)? From my knowledge, ComplexHeamtap can automatically merge the heamtap dendrograms when you split by a group variable. Details see: https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/a-single-heatmap.html#split-by-categorical-variables.
You don't have to merge the dendrogram by yourself.
The problem is something wrong in your matrix (maybe too many missing values), some issues similar with you has been asked in github:

https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/issues/155
https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/issues/938

